# Mysql replace regular expression

Tags: mysql, regex, replace

Hi is there any way to 'replace' all occurences of 10 or more occurances of _ (underscore) within a mysql table with something else.

**background**
I've inherited a database of content written for the web.

Unfortunately the origional author has used `________________` instead of `<hr />` for the horizontal rules.

It's a wordpress installation so the content is in a table called `wp_posts`.

I'm able to find the posts involved with the following query.

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_posts`
WHERE `post_content` LIKE '%\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_%'
```

**Update :**

I can find the posts that match using the following also

```
SELECT `post_content`
REGEXP '_{10,}'
FROM `wp_posts`
WHERE `post_content` LIKE '%\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_\_%'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

However that only returns 1 if theres a match not a 0 if there isn't.

Is there any way I can return the matching substring?
Is there a way to make the expression greedy?

Comment: @Dominic Rodger What was wrong with the post that you edited it?  Just want to know what I did wrong so as not to do it again.

Comment: nothing too serious (a couple of typos, and you needed backticks around `<hr />` - it didn't show up in your original post). People around here tend to edit things to tidy them up - it doesn't necessarily reflect badly on you as the question asker/answerer - this site is collaboratively edited (see the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MySQL does not have regular expression replace, but you can do what you want without it.

You can use [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) to replace an exact string:

```
update `wp_posts` set `post_content` = replace(`post_content`,'__________','<hr />');
```

Since this is a one-off job, I'd start by finding the highest count of `_`s used to represent an `<hr />` - if that is 15, I'd first run that SQL command with a string with 15 `_`s, then with 14, then with 13, then with..., then with 10.

Comment: Okay thats useful but I fear the origional author just kept the button held down for whatever length they deemed appropiate.

I may be able to use regex though to find those lengts and pass that into this. I'll give that a go.

Comment: if it's really important to use regex you can install it as a plugin in mysql, check here: http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_preg/

Comment: Okay this sort of worked for me. However I'll have to do the work again, I'd love to see a cleaner solution

Comment: Accepting the answer for "MySQL does not have regular expression replace" which ultimately is correct and may help most people.